# can there be a holomorphic function such that $f(\frac{1}{2^n})=\frac{1}{n}$ on the the set {|z|<1}

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

the Problem above, I've done the following and I'm not sure I'm correct.

if $f$ is analytic then $f(0)=0$ but $f\neq0$ therefore $0$ is a $0$ of rank $m\gt0$, therefore
$f(z)=z^mg(z)$ and $g$ is holomorphic.
$f(\frac{1}{2^n})=2^{-nm}g(2^{-n})=\frac{1}{n} $
then
$g(2^{-n})=\frac{2^{nm}}{n}$
then $g$ has a pole at $0$, therefore it is not holomorphic. contradiction.

Is that good? it's a new topic so I'm not sure.
Thanks

Comment: This may be useful, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem.

Comment: Why is there a $z$ in the exponent of $2$?

Comment: Your proof is okay. A simpler argument would be that the difference quotients $\frac{f(1/2^n)-f(0)}{1/2^n-0}=2^n/n$ do not converge so that $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @jjagmath mistake it's supposed to be n

Comment: @Jochen thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's good, except that, when you wrote $2^{-zm}$, you should have written $2^{-nm}$.

And from the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|g\left(\frac1{2^n}\right)\right|=\infty$, what you can deduce is that $0$ is a pole *or* an essential singularity of $g$. But if it was an essential singularity of $g$, then it would also be an essential singularity of $f$.